# How to read all google adwords targeting options using AWQL or Selectors?

Tags: java, google-ads-api

For example, I want to read Age Ranges, Genders, Operating Systems, etc, which are supported in google adwords. I want to read the above said targeting options using either AWQL or Selector?

I am able to read those targeting options using ConstantDataService.

```
    AdWordsServicesInterface adWordsServices = AdWordsServices.getInstance();
    ConstantDataServiceInterface constantDataService =
        adWordsServices.get(this.session, ConstantDataServiceInterface.class);
    AgeRange []ageRanges = constantDataService.getAgeRangeCriterion();
    for(AgeRange a : ageRanges) {
        System.out.println(a.getId() + " :: " + a.getAgeRangeType() + " :: " + a.getCriterionType() + " :: " + a.getType());
    }
```

But I am unable to apply filters. I saw that I can apply filters if I use AWQL or Selector? I tried the following

```
    AdGroupCriterionServiceInterface adGroupCriterionService =
            adWordsServices.get(session, AdGroupCriterionServiceInterface.class);

    // Create selector.
    SelectorBuilder builder = new SelectorBuilder();
    Selector selector = builder
            .fields("Id", "AgeRangeType")
            .build();

    int PAGE_SIZE = 100;

    ServiceQuery serviceQuery = new ServiceQuery.Builder().fields(AdGroupCriterionField.Id, AdGroupCriterionField.AgeRangeType).limit(0, PAGE_SIZE).build();

    // Set selector paging = the most important change is to set numberResults to 0.
    AdGroupCriterionPage page = null;

    do {
        serviceQuery.nextPage(page);
        page = adGroupCriterionService.query(serviceQuery.toString());
        if (page.getEntries() != null) {
            for (AdGroupCriterion criterion : page.getEntries()) {
                System.out.printf("Campaign with name '%s' and ID %d was found.%n", criterion.getAdGroupCriterionType(),
                        criterion.getCriterion());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No criterion were found.");
        }

    } while(serviceQuery.hasNext(page));
```

but not working as expected.

Can someone tell me how to read targeting options using AWQL or Selector?

Comment: What result did you except?

Comment: I am expecting a result like, for example to list of Age Ranges with id and type                          Id: 503999 :: AgeRangeType: AGE_RANGE_UNDETERMINED
Id: 503006 :: AgeRangeType: AGE_RANGE_65_UP 
Id: 503005 :: AgeRangeType: AGE_RANGE_55_64 
Id: 503004 :: AgeRangeType: AGE_RANGE_45_54 
Id: 503003 :: AgeRangeType: AGE_RANGE_35_44 
Id: 503002 :: AgeRangeType: AGE_RANGE_25_34 
Id: 503001 :: AgeRangeType: AGE_RANGE_18_24